# Cannot import managed solution: product updates must be installed for this solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to install my solution on the customer's test CRM. I export my solution from my dev CRM as managed, for target CRM 6.1. When I import the managed solution to the customer's Test CRM I get the error message:

```
For this solution product updates must be installed. Go to settings -> administration and click install product updates.
```

I translated this error message from German. Both CRMs (the dev and the test) have the version: 6.1.1.132 and the same DB version. Why do I get this error message and how can I resolve that problem?

I do not know if that is important, but when I export the solution from my dev CRM I get a warning, that some components need to be there in the target CRM for this solution to work. I would assume that the available components in the dev and the test CRM should be the same, since they have the same version. Is that correct?

Thanks and cheers,

Arne

Comment: I'd try going to Settings -> Administration and clicking Install Product Updates on the target server

Comment: That will update to CRM 2015 as far as I can see. I do not want that because that would have huge consequences. We would have to test everything again, etc. Plus, I do not see why an update is required when both CRMs have the same version.

Comment: Might it be that the target environment was not updated with the new Cases-related stuff despite being the same version ? All our environments are fully updated from the start so I have no way to verify this, unfortunately. ..

Comment: I see some cases related stuff in the list of missing items. How can I check this and perform the update?

Comment: Last clarification, proper answer to follow: do you have "Service Management" under Settings ?

Comment: No I do not have that.

Comment: Installing the update worked fine. And it did not update to 2015. Please post an answer an I will mark it to give you the credit for this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "target" server you are missing the Spring'14 updates (Service Management etc.)

You simply need to follow the instructions:

```
Settings > Administration > Install Product Updates
```

I tried to go there in one of our 2103 SP1 environments and I simply get "You have the latest update" (because all our environments are up to speed) so I wouldn't worry about 2015 try to sneak up on you.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks for that. Why do those updates not affect the version number? Are they distributed with Windows update? Because I do not remember to do this installation on my dev CRM.

Comment: I think that the installation itself increases the version number but this additional steps only enables the features in the environment (thus they *are* installed, but disabled)